# Indexing part of a array

Tags: arrays, go

I'm a total golang (1.8) n00b trying to quickly index part of an array. This is what I tried:

```
 8:   data := make([]byte, 10)
 9:   row := &data[3]
10:   fmt.Println(row[0])
```

The build error is:

```
10: invalid operation: row[0] (type *byte does not support indexing)
```

Gold star if you also know if there are any parallel primitives (mutex?) when accessing the `data` array, which could slow down writes, as opposed to letting each goroutine allocate an array of its own.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear? And if you consider yourself a n00b why are you interested in "parallel primitives"?

Comment: Welcome to Go! Not sure what you try to do though.  (8) `data` is a slice that can store 10 bytes.  (9) You copy a pointer to the 4th byte into the variable `row`. .. But then you try to access the first value of a pointer? That is not allowed. Unlike C, you cannot do pointer arithmetics. Is that what you wish to do?

Comment: @ANisus: so there is no way to optimize using a pointer to a part of the array? *Volker:* I'm not a n00b, just a go n00b.

Comment: @JonasByström It *is* possible using https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/ for generic pointers. But it is almost always better to work with *slices* (which differs from *arrays*, by the way) . You can create slices that points to a section of an underlying array or slice.

Comment: To the last question - Go has mutexes (see package `sync`), but arrays/slices are not thread-safe on their own (there is no locking mechanism built in to them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would suggest reading this [Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) to clarify the difference between *arrays* and *slices*.

Simply put:

- *Arrays* are a numbered sequence of elements.
- *Slices* contains a pointer to an underlying array element, a length and a capacity.

What you normally do with pointer arithmetic in languages like C, you do with slices in Go. Actually, you very seldom use arrays directly in Go.

**Slicing**

In your example, you can do the following:

```
data := make([]byte, 10) // Create a slice with length of 10
row := data[3:]          // Slicing a new slice starting from index 3. Length is 6
row[0] = 42
fmt.Println(data[3])
```

**Output:**

> 42

Using slicing, you pass different sections of an underlying array/slice to different Go routines to work on, without any races.

But if you instead want to have them work on the same slice, you can always protect it with a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) instead.